# C# Self Signed Certificate Custom Validation

Tags: c#, validation, self-signed

I'm trying to work out the best approach to validating a self signed certificate in an API process.

The certificate is manually generated and stored in the certificate store on both server and client machines using MMC. The client process looks up the certificate in certificate store and then adds to HttpClientHandle. API gets client certificate from request and looks up server certificate from certificate store.

All of this works but trying to figure out the best approach to validate the client certificate with server certificate. I know I have the public key from both and could compare but not sure if this is best approach or should I be looking at something else?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have a working process that I am comfortable with.

After obtaining client certificate and server certificate, the process will get a collection of chain elements from both. Will then loop through each client element comparing thumbprint to each server element thumbprint and if a match then certificate is valid.